# Issues with string appending - python

Tags: python, string, append

I'm trying to append a string in python and the following code produces

```
    buildVersion =request.values.get("buildVersion", None)
    pathToSave = 'processedImages/%s/'%buildVersion
    print pathToSave
```

prints out

```
   processedImages/V41
   /
```

I'm expecting the string to be of format: processedImages/V41/

It doesn't seem to be a new line character.

```
 pathToSave = pathToSave.replace("\n", "")
```

This dint really help

Comment: `buildVersion.rstrip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be relevant to actual question but, in addition to [Alex Martelli's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28652447/793428) answer, I would also check if `buildVersion` ever exists in the first place, because otherwise all solutions posted here will give you another errors:

```
import re

buildVersion = request.values.get('buildVersion')
if buildVersion is not None:
    return 'processedImages/{}/'.format(re.sub('\W+', '', buildVersion))
else:
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a `\r` or other special whitespace character.  Just clean up `buildVersion` of all such whitespace before executing

```
pathToSave = 'processedImages/%s/' % buildVersion
```

You can approach the clean-up task in several ways -- for example, if valid characters in `buildVersion` are only "word characters" (letters, digits, underscore), something like

```
import re
buildVersion = re.sub('\W+', '', buildVersion)
```

would usefully clean up even whitespace **inside** the string.  It's hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what characters you need to accept in `buildVersion`, of course.